# Equivalent of ActionController::Routing.possible_controllers in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mapping, routes

Just like the topic says, in Rails 2.3 I used to figure out what controllers were available in my app using

```
ActionController::Routing.possible_controllers
```

But this method appears to be removed from Rails 3.

Specifically what I'm trying to accomplish is getting a list of all available routed controllers (and eventually filter them by scope.)

If this isn't possible simply generating a list of all the applications controllers would do too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
all_routes = Rails.application.routes.routes
```

you can find more info here: http://pedromtavares.wordpress.com/2011/05/23/getting-your-rails-3-apps-routes-at-runtime/

Comment: Looks good! I'd found the routes method but hadn't figured out how to extract useful data ;) Thanks for the link!